# Client Categorization by Waybill Count

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am attempting to categorize clients based on the count of waybills using a ranking system in Power BI. The issue I am encountering is that the table only displays results when using a slicer on [Cities] (tested from 1 to 3); it doesn't work for the entire [Region] (about 10 cities).
Here are the DAX measures I'm using:

```
Count waybills = CALCULATE(SUM('my table'[waybill]))
Ranking client = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    [Count waybills] >= 3000, "A+",
    [Count waybills] >= 200, "A",
    [Count waybills] >= 50, "B",
    [Count waybills] >= 25, "C",
    [Count waybills] >= 5, "D",
    [Count waybills] >= 2, "E",
    [Count waybills] = 1, "F",
)
```

I would appreciate your feedback and recommendations on how to resolve the issue with the table not displaying results for all clients and the slicer not functioning effectively for the entire [Region]."

Comment: Perhaps share what your `'my table'` looks like, add a few sample rows and [paste as markdown table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/), to your question above. Alternatively, if you have sample pbix then post a public link to it (Google Drive, One Drive, Drop Box etc...)